# Logic gates: Why is the sum of 1 and 1 in an OR gate 1?

Tags: circuit

According to arithmetics of binary numbers, the sum would be 2 a decimal 2. This is 10 in binary. so the sum would be 0 and the carry 1.  But the carry is not represented in, right?

[image]

Comment: It's a logical Gate. You want to go out, but you need the autorisation of tutorA Or tutorB. They are both ok with it. Can you go out yes or no? It's not an addition the sign `+` is use to show a OR gate. like the encircled plus sign will be EXOR

Comment: @DragandDrop aha! so it is just logical not mathematical correct? there is no formula behind it?

Comment: Yes it's a logical operation. a logical gate. But the miss conception is viewing 1/0 as something else that yes/no, true/false.   Yes + Yes = Yes; Yes ⊕ Yes = No; Yes.Yes = Yes